# How to use preg-replace only when a condition is met

Tags: php

I already have code that works to replace links, such as

```
$pattern = "/href=['\"]{0,1}(\/|http:\/\/)/";
$replacement = "href=http://example.com/index.php?go=\\1";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
```

This works fine with any links that include "**http**" but now I need to replace links that are missing the "**http**" with a different replacement, for example...

```
 href="/images/some.gif"
```

Needs to be changed to...

```
href="http://example.com/images/some.gif"
```

And sometimes the link may be like

```
href="images/some.gif" without the / or even without the ".
```

Comment: You're giving an example with `src`, but your pattern checks for `href`.

Comment: Changed the src to href in the examples. But I have since realized that each replace needs to be treated differently because if quotes are found then the replacement needs to include a quote, the ones with apostrophe need an apostrophe and those with no quotes should have no quotes added because we are only modifying the beginning if the link... needs to match what exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, you are trying to match

```
href="http://example.com/images/some.gif"
href="images/some.gif"
```

and replace with

```
href="http://example.com/index.php?go=http://example.com/images/some.gif"
href="http://example.com/index.php?go=images/some.gif"
```

Try this pattern and replacement:

```
$pattern = '(href=["\']){1}(http:\/\/)?([a-z0-9_\-.\/]*)("|\'){1}';
$replacement = 'href="http://example.com/index.php?go=$2$3"';
```

### [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF3qM3/4)

### [Edit]

According to your comment, if you want to match no-quote HTML attribute values, append `?` to `["\']` making it `["\']?` and change `("|\'){1}` to `("|\')?`. It is not standard HTML and it is not recommended, though.

```
$pattern = '(href=["\']?){1}(http:\/\/)?([a-z0-9_\-.\/]*)("|\')?'
```

### [Updated Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF3qM3/5)

Comment: This works for some instances but fails on some combinations like: /some.gif and some.gif where quotes have not been used.

Comment: @WilliamK My answer could match double quote or single quote (apostrophe), but couldn't match no quote because no quote is not a valid HTML and you should not use it. Anyway, if you want to match no-quote, append `?` to `["\']` making it `["\']?` and change `("|\'){1}` to `("|\')?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$html = preg_replace('~((?:src|href)=["\']?)(?!http://)/?~', '$1http://', $html);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE9uD1/2)

However you should consider using `DOM` to reliably manipulate HTML.

Comment: This fails when quotes are not used.

Comment: Yes it does as none of your examples show a href/src without quotes. You need to draft all requirements in question.

Comment: Yes it does, see the last line.

Comment: I have the dom.class file but know how to use it. ASP I know but PHP is new to me as of 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_replace_callback` should solve it.
Something like this -

```
$html_list = Array(
                'href="images/some.gif"',
                'href="/images/some.gif"', 
                'href="http://example.com/images/some.gif"',
                'href=some.gif'
            );
$pattern = "/((?:href)=['\"]{0,1})(?:(\/)|([a-zA-Z])|(http:\/\/))/";
$replacement = "href=http://example.com/index.php?go=\\1";
foreach($html_list as $html){
    $string = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                function($m){
                    //print_r($m);
                    $r = $m[1];
                    if(!empty($m[2])){
                        return $r.'http://example.com/';

                    }if(isset($m[3]) && !empty($m[3])){
                        return $r.'http://example.com/'.$m[3];
                    }
                    //This matches http part
                    return $r.'http://example.com/index.php?go=';
                }
                , $html);
    print_r($string."\n");
}
```

OUTPUT -

```
href="http://example.com/images/some.gif"
href="http://example.com/images/some.gif"
href="http://example.com/http://example.com/images/some.gif"
href=http://example.com/some.gif
```